# Nested transclude directive renders inner transcluded content in wrong place

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-transclude

I have a `myList` directive, which transcludes it's content. The problem occurs when I try and nest a `<my-list>` element inside another `<my-list>`.

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fqj5svhn/

The directive:

```
var MyListDirective = (function () {
    function MyListDirective() {
        this.restrict = 'E';
        this.replace = true;
        this.transclude = true;
        this.scope = {
            myListType: '='
        };
        this.controller = function () {
            this.classes = 'my-class';
        };
        this.controllerAs = 'myList';
        this.bindToController = true;
        this.template = '<ul ng-class="myList.classes" ng-transclude></ul>';
    }
    return MyListDirective;
})();
angular.module('myApp', []).directive('myList', function () {
    return new MyListDirective();
});
```

Example usage of the directive:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <my-list my-list-type="'someType'">
        <li>foo</li>
        <li>bar</li>
        <li>
            <my-list my-list-type="'anotherType'">
                <li>cats</li>
                <li>dogs</li>
            </my-list>
        </li>
    </my-list>
</div>
```

What gets rendered:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" class="ng-scope">
    <ul ng-class="myList.classes" ng-transclude="" my-list-type="'someType'" class="ng-isolate-scope my-class">
        <li class="ng-scope">foo</li>
        <li class="ng-scope">bar</li>
        <li class="ng-scope">
            <ul ng-class="myList.classes" ng-transclude="" my-list-type="'anotherType'" class="ng-isolate-scope my-class">
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="ng-scope">cats</li>
        <li class="ng-scope">dogs</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

As you can see the list items from the inner `myList` appear to be transcluded by the outer `myList`.
What I want to happen:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" class="ng-scope">
    <ul ng-class="myList.classes" ng-transclude="" my-list-type="'someType'" class="ng-isolate-scope my-class">
        <li class="ng-scope">foo</li>
        <li class="ng-scope">bar</li>
        <li class="ng-scope">
            <ul ng-class="myList.classes" ng-transclude="" my-list-type="'anotherType'" class="ng-isolate-scope my-class">
                <li class="ng-scope">cats</li>
                <li class="ng-scope">dogs</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is happening because when browser renders the page it expects `<li>` to be inside `<ul>`, but it your case it is inside `<my-list>` which is an invalid markup. All these things happen before Angular bootstraps and runs directives. There is no way you can predict how the browser would interpret your markup when it's invalid, in this particular case it pushes `<li>`'s out to be together.

In this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/scndvdL6/1/) I've replaced `<ul>` and `<li>` with `<div>`, which does not have any requirements for nesting, and transclusion works just fine.

Comment: Thanks - that is indeed the problem. I'd ideally like to be using the correct list elements, so leaving the question unanswered for now.

Comment: I wonder if it is possible for you to use `<ul my-list>` instead of `<my-list`> i.e. `restrict: 'A'` vs `restrict: 'E'`, so you could keep markup valid and at the same time apply a directive to an element. See example [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/scndvdL6/2/).

Comment: Great suggestion - I'm leaning towards that.The only reason I don't like it is that it is different to the rest of my directive "api" (e.g. annotating element vs custom element).

Comment: I went with the attribute option. For completeness, the other option was to have a `myListItem` directive for each `li`. http://jsfiddle.net/fqj5svhn/4/

Comment: Yeah, but I thought it would be overhead. I was trying also to make `<mylist>` behave like `<ul>` but did not succeed. For general information, there is a `document.registerElement` or [polyfill](https://github.com/WebReflection/document-register-element), where you could inherit behavior from native HTML elements, but seems that it's not possible to do a complete inheritance and even if it would then, as a whole, solution it too tricky.